# clang libtooling: Get Preprocessor object in clang libtool

Tags: clang, libtooling

I want to get macro names from my source files.
Going through a couple of answers I found that

> clang::Preprocessor::getPredefines()

does the job.

Question is how to get preprocessor object in ClangTool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm also a newbie in clang. In my humble opinion, you misunderstood how to use the APIs.

Because you want to do preprocessing, so I guess you need [PreprocessOnlyAction](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1PreprocessOnlyAction.html) and [FrontendActionFactory](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1tooling_1_1FrontendActionFactory.html). PreprocessOnlyAction inherits clang::FrontendAction which can give you an instance of CompilerInstance by calling `getCompilerInstance ()`. The good thing is this instance has a member function [getPreprocessor()](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CompilerInstance.html#a6bb2c55eefbddd0e9ad56ebdce22fd70). This is what you want.

Take a look at [EndSourceFile()](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FrontendAction.html#a0c0da9a416e556c83ab65e1a2691c0f2). [ClangCheck](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/clang/tools/clang-check/ClangCheck.cpp) can help you better understand how to use them (based on AST instead of Preprocessor).